# Problem with nginx container to reverse proxy rancher container with rewrite url

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, rancher

on my docker host. With nginx container, i try to reverse proxy multiple services by using url name to identify the right service (portainer, rancher).

trafic from https://host1/rancher => https/rancher-container

trafic from https://host1/portainer => http://portainer-container:9000

I configure nginx to use url rewrite for transform the url before send it to the good service. 
It works for service portainer. But it's don't work for rancher 2 service.

Here is my configuration:

```
    location /rancher/ {
       rewrite ^/rancher^/ /$1 break;
       proxy_pass         https://rancher-container;
       proxy_redirect     off;
       proxy_set_header   Host $host;
       proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
       proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
     }

    location /portainer/ {
      rewrite ^/portainer^/ /$1 break;
      proxy_pass         http://portainer-container:9000/;
      proxy_redirect     off;
      proxy_set_header   Host $host;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
      proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
    }
```

When I look from my chromeDevTools, I see:

GET https://host1/rancher/   200 OK (and return index page like this) : 
    
        `<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        ...
        <link id="vendor" rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/vendor.css">
        ...
        <script src="/assets/vendor-ebb1f9e6b4381d69a55448a2a5d7e4c9.js"></script>
        <script src="/assets/ui-72ee502ee50a84d0f416c3164137307d.js"></script>
        ...`
 
GET https://host1/assets/vendor.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404
GET https://host1/assets/vendor-ebb1f9e6b4381d69a55448a2a5d7e4c9.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
GET https://host1/assets/ui-72ee502ee50a84d0f416c3164137307d.js

I think my web browser try to get ressources (css, js, img ..etc) define on html page with relative url like '/assets/' to 'https://host1/assets'. Or the good url is 'https://host1/racher/assets'.

Is there some solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Check the website. Probably in the HTML code your website has no idea that it's running not on extra path but assumes it's on root. Perhaps there's some switch that you can setup a base path for the website to know where it is.

Unfortunately this is a quite common problem. Default proxy headers does not send original path so services hidden behind usually are unaware that request is for something other than /.

If the service behind proxy is yours, you can pass some additional header like x-proxy-urlpath and inform service that it should render links including that path.

If not and you cannot setup base url in the website - the best solution would be to use subdomains and host-based proxy.